# How to handle drop down using javascript executor

Tags: java, javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

How can we select different values in dropdown using javascript executor in Selenium WebDriver?

I've tried `document.getElementById` to get the dropdown box. Here's the code snippet:

```
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("return document.getElementByID('id');");
```

I am getting error while executing this code.

Comment: I've tried document.getElementById to get the dropdown box. Here's the code snippet: ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("return document.getElementByID('id');");                                                                                      I am getting error while executing this code.

Comment: Please add those details in the question, not in comments.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using javascript executor with code snippet:

```
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("return document.getElementById('id').selectedIndex = '" + index + "';)
```

Answer (score 0):

its bad idea try to do this via javascript executor. Much easier will be to use selenium.support lib. More details here:

http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/Select.html

you will be able to find by id, assign to select element from this lib and select option needed by value/index/text.

Comment: Thanks Andrew, with webdriver we have done, but on one page nothing is getting handled with webdriver for firefox browser(Page is new window opened clicking any link on parent window), other things also done using javascriptExecuter on this page. so I was aslo finding the way to handle drop down with javascriptExecuter/javascript.

Comment: This can be done using javascript with code                                                     ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("return document.getElementById('id').selectedIndex = '" + index + "';)